# Find Row Value Based on Another Value in Same Row

Tags: mysql, sql

For a MOD that I am attempting to write for phpBB, I need to know how to find a value in a row of a MySQL database table based off of another row in the table. For example, say that this is my table.

```
Row_Id | Name | Birthday
————————————————————————
   1   | Bob  | 1/19/1965
   2   | Ann  | 9/15/1968
```

How could I find the person’s name based off of the row ID? I haven't been able to figure it out, and Googling around warranted no results. I need the data that I get to be echoed using PHP, but I already understand how to do that.

Comment: what do you actually want? a sql query?

Comment: `SELECT Name FROM MyTable WHERE Row_Id = 1;` ?

Comment: is this homework? but CORRECT has it on the right end that query will do what you ask.

Comment: @zzlalani Yes. Once I have a SQL query, I can set it up in PHP very nicely.

Comment: Missing something here. If you want to find Bob based on Ann's birthday or name, how do you know Bob and Ann are related?

Comment: @RaymondNijland No, it is something that I am trying to do for fun.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson No, want I want to do is find a person's name based on the id in the same row. For exmaple, I want "Bob" to be returned when I search for column "Name" in row with "Row_Id" 1.

Comment: @user2850226 Ok NP this sounded like homework...

Comment: Ah well you fooled me when you asked how to find it based on another row in the table, when you meant an other column...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Row_Id = $id
```

Comment: Please don't steal CORRUPT's answer and read the comments first..

Comment: is it stealing? you want me to make some other query when this is a simple solution?

Comment: i dont mind if @CORRUPT write the answer rather then commenting, so it will help other..

Comment: although I dont think any one will be looking for this but this is going to be a big hit because every newbie will come here and will find no solution.

Comment: Lol but how many disk space we wasted now i am wondering?

Comment: Kindly CORRUPT make your answer and I will delete my answer on the first thing to make @RaymondNijland happy :)

Comment: @CORRUPT Okay, thank you everyone. If CORRUPT is okay with it,  will accept this answer.

Comment: well actually this is stackoverflows responsibility to dont allow such questions and rather suggest them what they are looking for already answered million times.. :)

Comment: @user2850226 accept. I've upvoted it (: There is no copyright.

Comment: well the matter of fact is that they are already doing this but to be honest sometimes it difficult to find things when you are tried of looking for something whole day and find nothing ..

Comment: since everyone is happy cheers to stackoverflow .. @user2850226 you must thank to stack over flow.. :D

Comment: what an comment can do ... copyright o you mean copyleft or copytheft i like it...

Comment: @zzlalani Well, "RTFM" will help in those cases: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: lol @CORRUPT what happened?

Comment: @zzlalani lets stop it. It became too chatty. :)

Comment: Yeah, but it's fun! Sometimes I think that SO's strictness is overrated. Also, I aparently forget how to echo the result.

Comment: sometimes SO is more like an Role model playing adventure and not an chat... (action gives an reaction)

Comment: Sometimes SO is stupid the way they remove things, and other times they are right about it.